# Extracting unstructured data from a txt or json file in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parsing, text

I have an unstructured data. Its on my server so, I'm saving it in **txt** format on my computer to iterate and filter the data. This is how my code looks like:

```
with open('dev.txt') as f:
    dev = f.read()

def parser_dev(dev):
    filtered_status = {}
    vpn_list = re.findall("vpn.*", dev, re.MULTILINE)
    status_list = re.findall("{\"devices.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*", dev, re.MULTILINE)
    ETA_productid = ['1','2','8','9','21','22']
    switch_productid=['34']
    for i, pattern in enumerate(status_list):
        json_object = json.loads(pattern)
        adapters = []
        switches = {}
        for key, value in json_object["devices"].items():
            if key.startswith("ETA"):
                #print('key---',key)
                if value["EbStatus"] != "0x80c0":
                    #print('value---',value)
                    if value["productid"] in ETA_productid:
                        adapters.append(key)
                    if value["productid"] in switch_productid:
                        switches[key] = value["canaddr"]

        if len(adapters) > 0 or len(switches) > 0:
            filtered_status[vpn_list[i]] = {
                'adapters':adapters,
                'switches':switches
            }
    return filtered_status
```

As soon as I run this, I have an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\vaibhav.ghildiyal\Desktop\logParser.py", line 159, in <module> 
    filtered_vpns = parser_dev(dev)
  File "c:\Users\vaibhav.ghildiyal\Desktop\logParser.py", line 73, in parser_dev
    json_object = json.loads(pattern)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 8 column 1 (char 174)
```

I realized that this problem when I checked my txt file which was pretty unstructured. This is how my **txt** looks like:

```
vpn13_000000029
solaredge.py = "0.16"
emsc2 = /opt/emsc2/emsc2.0.9.13
solardge.py procs = 4

{"devices":
{"EMSC2":
{"canaddr":"0.1","deviceType":"EMSC2","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"4","revision":"1","serial":"0","status":"1","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA1":
{"EbStatus":"0x80c0","canaddr":"0.2","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"9","revision":"3791667201","serial":"124","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA2":
{"EbStatus":"0x80c0","canaddr":"0.3","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"9","revision":"3791667201","serial":"154","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA3":
{"EbStatus":"0x80c0","canaddr":"0.4","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"34","revision":"2684362766","serial":"0","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
}
},"errorcode":0
}

vpn13_000000005
vpn13_000000028
vpn13_000000015
solaredge.py = "0.14"
emsc2 = /opt/emsc2/emsc2.0.9.12
solardge.py procs = 4

{"devices":
{"EMSC2":
{"canaddr":"0.1","deviceType":"EMSC2","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"4","revision":"1","serial":"0","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA1":
{"EbStatus":"0x4040","canaddr":"0.2","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"9","revision":"3791667201","serial":"227","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA2":
{"EbStatus":"0x4040","canaddr":"0.3","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"9","revision":"3791667201","serial":"147210004","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA3":
{"EbStatus":"0x2040","canaddr":"0.4","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"34","revision":"2684362766","serial":"0","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
}
},"errorcode":0
}

vpn13_000000015
solaredge.py = "0.16"
emsc2 = /opt/emsc2/emsc2.0.9.13
solardge.py procs = 4

{"devices":
{"EMSC2":
{"canaddr":"0.1","deviceType":"EMSC2","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"4","revision":"1","serial":"0","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA1":
{"EbStatus":"0x80c0","canaddr":"0.2","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"9","revision":"3791667201","serial":"116","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA2":
{"EbStatus":"0x4040","canaddr":"0.3","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"9","revision":"3791667201","serial":"163","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA3":
{"EbStatus":"0x4180","canaddr":"0.4","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"34","revision":"2684362766","serial":"0","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
}
},"errorcode":0
}

vpn13_000000006
solaredge.py = "0.16"
emsc2 = /opt/emsc2/emsc2.0.9.13
solardge.py procs = 0

{"devices":
{"EMSC2":
{"canaddr":"0.1","deviceType":"EMSC2","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"4","revision":"1","serial":"0","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA1":
{"EbStatus":"0x4040","canaddr":"0.2","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"9","revision":"3791667201","serial":"170","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA2":
{"EbStatus":"0x4040","canaddr":"0.3","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"9","revision":"3791667201","serial":"172","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA3":
{"EbStatus":"0x8080","canaddr":"0.4","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"34","revision":"2684362766","serial":"0","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
}
},"errorcode":0
}

vpn13_000000027
solaredge.py = "0.16"
emsc2 = /opt/emsc2/emsc2.0.9.13
solardge.py procs = 4

{"devices":
{"EMSC2":
{"canaddr":"0.1","deviceType":"EMSC2","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"4","revision":"1","serial":"0","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA1":
{"EbStatus":"0x80c0","canaddr":"0.2","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"9","revision":"3791667201","serial":"217","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA2":
{"EbStatus":"0x80c0","canaddr":"0.3","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"9","revision":"3791667201","serial":"218","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA3":
{"EbStatus":"0x80c0","canaddr":"0.4","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"34","revision":"2684362766","serial":"0","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
}
},"errorcode":0
}

tannheim01
solaredge.py = "0.14"
emsc2 = /opt/emsc2/emsc2.0.9.12
solardge.py procs = 4

{"devices":
{"EMSC2":
{"canaddr":"0.1","deviceType":"EMSC2","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"4","revision":"1","serial":"0","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
}
},"errorcode":0
}

vpn13_000000014
solaredge.py = "0.16"
emsc2 = /opt/emsc2/emsc2.0.9.13
solardge.py procs = 4

{"devices":
{"EMSC2":
{"canaddr":"0.1","deviceType":"EMSC2","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"4","revision":"1","serial":"0","status":"1","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA1":
{"EbStatus":"0x80c0","canaddr":"0.2","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"9","revision":"3791667201","serial":"142","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA2":
{"EbStatus":"0x80c0","canaddr":"0.3","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"9","revision":"3791667201","serial":"179","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
},"ETA3":
{"EbStatus":"0x80c0","canaddr":"0.4","deviceType":"ETA","ipaddr":"0.0.0.0","productid":"34","revision":"2684362766","serial":"0","status":"0","vendorid":"969"
}
},"errorcode":0
}
```

Would be great to hear some suggestions on how to filter out important data and some key value pairs from this data structure. Example:

**a list of ids**= vpn13_000000005,vpn13_000000028 ,vpn13_000000015,tannheim01

**key value pairs for** = EbStatus":"0x80c0"

**key value pairs for** = productid":"4"

**a list of ETAs** = ETA1, ETA2, ETA3

so on and so forth. Thank you!

Comment: Given the fact that it's unstructured, you'd have to manually read the file line by line and then parse out the information.  For the non-json info, it's simple.  For the json info, you'll need to read all the data between the { and } and then join them into one long string and then use ```json.loads()```.   That'd be my suggestion.

Comment: i suggest read file content into text, then regex search some patterns (like json {}), then parse with library(json)